# Convert OkHttp's HttpUrl to a relative url

Tags: okhttp

How can I convert a HttpUrl to a relative url, e.g. `https://example.com/fo/o?bar#baz` to `/fo/o?bar#baz`?

Comment: There's nothing built in.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a great solution.  Most obviously one of

1. building it from components your self, like path, query, fragment.
2. Applying a stripping regex.
3. Removing a common prefix.

So option 3

```
  val u = "https://example.com/fo/o?bar#baz".toHttpUrl()
  val u2 = u.resolve("/")
  println(u) // https://example.com/fo/o?bar#baz
  println(u2) // https://example.com/

  println(u.toString().substring(u2.toString().length - 1)) // /fo/o?bar#baz
```